# How can I check server configuration ("$ httpd -S") in MAMP?

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost

I have previously installed Apache on my Mac Mini using Homebrew, but I'm currently using MAMP. When I issue the terminal command `httpd -S` to check Apache configurations, it checks the Homebrew configurations. Is there a way I can test the configurations for MAMP? I would like to use the same `httpd -S` command, but if there's another preferred way to do it for MAMP, that's fine too.

Comment: I'm not a Mac user, but I imagine you'll need to either type the full path, create an alias or add the directory to PATH in an earlier position. Do you really need to have two Apache distributions running side by side?

Comment: Only the MAMP one is running. But even if I removed the Homebrew-installed one, typing the command `httpd -S` won't find the MAMP Apache.
I like your thought on adding the directory to PATH, I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it with the `-f` flag, like this:

```
 httpd -f /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf -S
```

This is in `httpd` options:

```
Options:
 ...
  -f file: specify an alternate ServerConfigFile
```